# Reading a List<(string,string[])> from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to read "Products" to a List<(string,string[])> variable. appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Products": [
    {"fruits":["apple","cherry","tomato"]},
    {"vegetables":["carrot","tomato"]}
  ]
}
```

Note: Please presuppose that I cannot change this appsettings.json entry format. But the variable could also be an array of ValueTuple instead of a List of ValueTuple. ValueTuple format must be (string category,string[] items).

Thanks to @Serge for the great answer ! I'm sure I'm not alone struggling with linq and that config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 var products = Configuration
 .GetSection("Products")
 .Get<Dictionary<string, string[]>[]>()
 .SelectMany(i => i)
 .Select(i => new Tuple<string, string[]>(i.Key, i.Value)) // or you can convert here to any class
 .ToList();
```

Comment: That's very elegant ! I tried it and it works just great. Thanks !

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: I used this "Select(i => (i.Key, i.Value))" since I want System.ValueTuple. I wonder what the "new" changes.

Comment: Tuples are very tricky. I would prefer to leave keyvalue pair  or convert to a concrete class

Comment: For now I'll stick with ValueTuple since it offers the advantages I'm looking for e.g. renaming Item1 and Item2 fields, mutable, IComparable and IStructuralEquatable.